# Manipulating HTML from the asp.net code-behind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am able to get the HTML from the code-behind, like this one:

```
protected override void OnPreRenderComplete(EventArgs e)
{
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    base.Render(new HtmlTextWriter(sw));
    sbHtml = sw.GetStringBuilder();
    Response.Write(sbHtml + "<!-- processed by code-behind -->");
}
```

But I need to remove the HTML from the Page, any help?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific with what you want to do?

Comment: This is an odd question. You clearly have access to the page itself, so why not just write the page differently (i.e. add/change/remove text from the .aspx) rather than messing with OnPreRenderComplete(). Can you tell us what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: are you using server controls or do you want to compose and render all the page simply by kicking out raw HTML like in your example above using StringWriter?

Comment: To remove all the html from the page you can use `Response.Clear();` But the best solution would to remove the controls you don't want to render from the page.

Comment: More specific: Integrating with another API, which needs to parse the HTML and returns final one. This integration needs to be done only on certain situation, other situations I have leave it as such.

Comment: Interesting I didn't expect this to be this hard and also as a odd question. Empty anything inside <asp:placeholder> is not easy it seems.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand well you wish to manipulate the sbHtml, and write it out.

```
sbHtml = sw.GetStringBuilder();

sbHtml.Replace('anything','to anything');

Response.Write(sbHtml);
```

(or is something else ?)

Answer (score 2):

Did you want a method like this to strip the HTML?

```
public static string StripHTML(string HTMLText)
{
    var reg = new Regex("<[^>]+>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return reg.Replace(HTMLText, "").Replace("&nbsp;", "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put an `<asp:placeholder>` on the page and set the contents to whatever you want.  Add/remove/whatever.